# ng cli: Need to pass environment from local environment variable in OSX

Tags: macos, environment-variables, angular-cli

I want to use the app and environment values dynamically through cli tool and read them from local environment variable.

I am setting these values in env as

```
//Windows
set APP_NAME=my_app
set ENV=development

//MAC
APP_NAME=my_app
ENV=development
```

I have following:

**package.json**:

```
scripts : {
    "start": "npm run start:mac",
    "start:mac": "ng serve --aot false --port 3001 --app $APP_NAME --environment $ENV",
    "start:win": "ng serve --aot false --port 3001 --app %APP_NAME% --environment %ENV%"
}
```

**angular-cli.json**:

```
"apps": [
    {
      "name": "my_app",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "my_app/app/main.browser.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "development": "environments/my_app/environment.development.ts",
        "prod": "environments/my_app/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }]
```

While this works fine in Windows with command "npm run start:win", it is failing in Mac for command "npm start", with error as

```
Environment "" does not exist
```

So it seems to be not accepting the --environment as a environment variable in OSX.
I have tried to use ENV1 as env var name, but it doesn't help.
If I am not doing wrong, is there any alternative to achieve same?